# How to bypass bluetooth pairing dialog in LG nexus 4 (E960)?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I am connecting a embedded Bluetooth device with LG nexus 4 in my application using following code

```
private void pairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {

    BluetoothSocket tmp = null;


    try {
        tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID
                .fromString("<UUID of embedded device>"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.v("log_tag", "socket found");

    try {
        tmp.connect();
        Log.v("log_tag", "connected");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

its working fine in other devices like Samsung Galaxy Grand but when I am trying with LG nexus 4 it shows me a dialog with two options pair or cancel and I do not want that it should be directly connect with device. please help me.